# How to unzip a column in a Spark DataFrame using pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am working on a dataframe with a compressed column. I want to unzip it by using the zlib.decompress. The following code snippet is my try:

```
from zlib import decompress
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf
toByteStr = udf(bytes)
unzip = udf(decompress)
df = (spark.read.format("xx.xxx.xx.xx").
  load())
df1 = df.withColumn("message", unzip(toByteStr("content"), 15+32))
```

The following message is the error I got:

```
An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.sql.functions.col. Trace:
py4j.Py4JException: Method col([class java.lang.Integer]) does not exist
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.getMethod(ReflectionEngine.java:318)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.getMethod(ReflectionEngine.java:339)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:274)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:214)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Traceback (most recent call last):
```

I really need your help to solve it. Thanks.

**more information:**

I just realized that the real data was compress in pkzip format which is not support by zlib. I am trying to use the following code to unzip it.

```
import StringIO
import zipfile
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf

def unZip(buf):
    fio = StringIO.StringIO(buf)
    z = zipfile.ZipFile(fio, 'r')
    result = z.open(z.infolist()[0]).read()
    return result

toByteStr = udf(bytes, StringType())
unzip = udf(unZip, StringType())

df = (spark.read.format("xxx.xxx.xxx.xx").
  option("env", "xxx").
  option("table", "xxxxx.xxxxxx.xxxx").
  load())

df1 = df.withColumn("message", unzip(toByteStr("content")))
df1.show()
```

I tried the "**unZip**" function with a Zip string, it works well. But when I want to register as a udf and work parallel on spark cluster, it shows me the file is not zip file but I am quite sure it is. The error is below:

```
BadZipfile: File is not a zip file
    at 
org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.read(PythonRDD.scala:193)
at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.<init>(PythonRDD.scala:234)
at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner.compute(PythonRDD.scala:152)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.BatchEvalPythonExec$$anonfun$doExecute$1.apply(BatchEvalPythonExec.scala:144)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.BatchEvalPythonExec$$anonfun$doExecute$1.apply(BatchEvalPythonExec.scala:87)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitions$1$$anonfun$apply$23.apply(RDD.scala:797)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitions$1$$anonfun$apply$23.apply(RDD.scala:797)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
```

Answer (score 1):

The second argument should be a `Column` as well, so you'll need to use the `lit` function :

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import lit

df.withColumn("message", unzip(toByteStr("content"), lit(15 + 32)))
```

Comment: sorry, i know this thread is old.. what does the lit(15+32) bit do please?